# How to write unit test case for on click handlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am able to just find if elements exist or not as of now. I tried mocking function and simulate handle click but couldn't get through. Please guide me on how to handle the button click. When redirect to is empty, a button has to be handled checking if either function with name buttonOnClickHandler is called or modalHandler is called.

```
{isEmpty(redirectTo) ? 
      (<button
        type="button"
        className="help__more-info c-link"
        onClick={buttonOnClickHandler ? buttonOnClickHandler : this.modalHandler}
      ><span className="c-link__icon">
        <img alt={altText || "More Info"} src={icon} />
      </span>
        <span className="c-link__text">
          {buttonText}
        </span>
      </button>) : (
        <a className="c-link" href={redirectTo}>
          <span className="c-link__icon">  
            <img alt={altText || "More Info"} src={icon} />
          </span>
          <span className="c-link__text">
            {linkText || "More Info"}
          </span>
        </a>
      )
    }
```

and test case i tried to write is as follows

```
describe("When re direction link is defined", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            component.setProps({
                redirectTo: ""
            });
        })
        it("Should have 1 button", () => {
            expect(component.find("button").length).toEqual(1);
        });
        it("Should have 1 image", () => {
            expect(component.find("img").length).toEqual(1);
        });
        // describe("When button is clicked", () => {
        //     it('function should have been called', () => {
        //         const modalHandler =  jest.fn();
        //         component = mount(< HelpComponent {...props} />);
        //         component.find('.c-link').at(0).simulate('click');
        //         expect(modalHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
        //     })
        // })
    });
```

Please refer to the pen where i have shared **both Js and test files.** 
    https://codepen.io/arunkgowda/pen/RwbmmQj

Comment: You can create a spy and pass it as props. Then simulate button's click and expect the spy to have been called

Comment: Hi Rajesh, could you please explain me with the code. I am new to development. Wouldn't be able to figure out with the inputs given above